# specific column name on postgres function return

Tags: postgresql, function

In postgres I have a custom function that will join first and last name.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION full_name(u users) RETURNS varchar
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  AS $$
    BEGIN
      RETURN CONCAT_WS(' ', u.first_name, u.last_name);
    END;
  $$;
```

It would be nice if I didn't have to set the the name of the column name and it was determined by the function eg.

eg. here I have to say the column name is full_name

```
SELECT
 full_name(users) as full_name
```

But it would be nice if it atomically name it full_name

```
SELECT
full_name(users)
```

Is this possible to set in a custom function?

Answer (score 2):

As the function parameter is the name of the table, you don't have to pass it.

You can call it like this:

```
select users.full_name
from users;
```

Note that you *have* to prefix the function name with the table name. You can also use an alias, but you still need the prefix.

```
select u.full_name
from users u;
```

In that case the column from the result set will be named `full_name` (the name of the function)

Btw: you don't need PL/pgSQL for the function. A plain SQL will likely be faster for this. Eespecially when you declare it `stable` instead of `volatile` - the it can be inlined and the overhead of calling the function is eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `out` parameter instead of returning the value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION full_name(in u users, out full_name varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
AS $$
  BEGIN
    full_name := CONCAT_WS(' ', u.first_name, u.last_name);
  END;
$$;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM full_name(users)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution to your problem. Instead of passing users as parameter you can use the first_name and last_name as parameters to the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION full_name(character varying ,character varying)
 RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
declare
    l_nom ALIAS FOR $1;
    l_pnom ALIAS FOR $2;
begin

    RETURN CONCAT_WS(' ', l_nom, l_pnom);    
 end;$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
     ALTER FUNCTION full_name(character varying ,character varying) OWNER TO postgres;

SELECT full_name(u.first_name, u.last_name)
```